# SignalR Server with TCP connection

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, signalr, listener

is there any way to create a TCP listener and clients  and make them Communicate with each other using SignalR?

in other words make the signalr server like a virtual switch to manage the connections
like if we give All connected clients just the signalR server IP Address and make the signalR server manage the Connection

I know my question is hard to understand , Iam new student who don't have a big experience  and love to learn , Pleas Help :)